# how to search for two value in range collectivly in VBA Excel

Tags: loops, for-loop, find, range, rows

The code has got a searching order and what it does is as following:

It takes each value in ws.range A and looks it up in another sheet named wp.range A. If a particular value x in ws.range e.g A3 is not found in wp.range A the next search order in sheet "ws" is the value y in the next range B3 (same row as value x) to be searched in sheet "wp" in the entire range B. If not, the next value in range C (sheet ws) is considered to be found in the other sheet wp in column C.

Now, If values in range A and then in range B are not found then the values not only in range C but in range C and D are collectively be taken for comparison. But the code:

```
 Set foundValue = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range(Cells(ru, I + 1), 
 Cells(number_of_ru, I + 1)).Find(cell.Offset(0, I).Value) And
 wp.Sheets("ABC").Range(Cells(ru, I + 2), 
 Cells(number_of_ru, I + 2)).Find(cell.Offset(0, I + 1).Value)
```

gives me the error message: "type incompatible"

```
Dim cell As Range
r = 2
number_of_r = 30
ru = 1
number_of_ru = 30


For Each cell In ws.Range("A" & r & ":A" & number_of_r)
For I = 0 To 2 'Column Offset form A to C
  Set foundValue = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range(Cells(ru, I + 
1), Cells(number_of_ru, I + 1)).Find(cell.Offset(0, I).Value)
If Not foundValue Is Nothing Then
    wp.Sheets("ABC").Rows(foundValue.Row).Columns("E:AB").Copy
    ws.Range("G" & cell.Row).PasteSpecial
    GoTo nextCell
End If
Next I
     Set foundValue = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range(Cells(ru, I + 1), 
    Cells(number_of_ru, I + 1)).Find(cell.Offset(0, I).Value) And 
    wp.Sheets("ABC").Range(Cells(ru, I + 2), Cells(number_of_ru, I + 
    2)).Find(cell.Offset(0, I + 1).Value)
    If Not foundValue Is Nothing Then
        wp.Sheets("ABC").Rows(foundValue.Row).Columns("E:AB").Copy
        ws.Range("G" & cell.Row).PasteSpecial
        GoTo nextCell
    Else: MsgBox "Problem"
    End If
nextCell:
Next cell

End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 For Each cell In ws.Range("A" & r & ":A" & number_of_r)
 For I = 0 To 2 'Column Offset form A to C
 Set foundValue = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range(Cells(ru, I + 
 1), Cells(number_of_ru, I + 1)).Find(cell.Offset(0, I).Value)
If Not foundValue Is Nothing Then
wp.Sheets("ABC").Rows(foundValue.Row).Columns("E:AB").Copy
ws.Range("G" & cell.Row).PasteSpecial
GoTo nextCell
End If
Next I
 Set foundValue = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range(Cells(ru, I + 1), 
Cells(number_of_ru, I + 1)).Find(cell.Offset(0, I).Value) 
  If Not foundValue Is Nothing Then
 Set foundValue = wp.Sheets("ABC").Range(Cells(ru, I + 2), Cells(number_of_ru, I + 
2)).Find(cell.Offset(0, I + 2).Value)
If Not foundValue Is Nothing Then
    wp.Sheets("ABC").Rows(foundValue.Row).Columns("E:AB").Copy
    ws.Range("G" & cell.Row).PasteSpecial
    GoTo nextCell
   End If 
Else: MsgBox "Problem"
End If
nextCell:
Next cell

End sub
```